# Can I merge two repositories and clone it to my system using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, git, github

I want to merge two different git repositories, one repository will have a skeleton code and other will have generated code. I want to merge these two repository using an API using node js. How can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [git package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git) to manage git repositories

To merge 2 repositories you should

1. Clone the first one as master branch
2. Add another remote which point to the second one (after you generate it)
3. Fetch from second one
4. Checkout the second one to local branch
5. Merge to master with `--allow-unrelated-histories`

To find all the required commands you can check the source [here](https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-merge-two-repositories-on-git-b0ed5e3b4448) andyou need to learn how to use the git package.

Then you can build a web app that will do all of the above as an API service.

As far as I know there is no existing API that will do it for you.

Another example of the commands can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/msrose/2feacb303035d11d2d05)